# Is there anyway to calculate the exact execution time of deep learning algorithm in each epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working to compare two DL algorithms in terms of computation time. How I can calculate the exact execution time in one Iteration?

Comment: In one epoch or one iterarion?

Comment: _italic_ One epoch

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Tensorflow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras). It works with Tensorboard and you don't need to change much to your code.